# Sencha touch 2 list paging with plugin

Tags: sencha-touch-2, paging

I have Ext.List item where i want to apply paging, i found a plugin 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging'. But it did not work in my solution. I search some examples about its usage, and i found the only difference is loading data to store. My case is like that,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ListTemplate', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    plugins: [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true
        }
    ]},
    itemTpl: '<div class="listContainer"><div class="listItemTitle">{listItemTitle}</div><div class="elapsedTime"><tpl if="listItemDate != null">{listItemDate}</tpl></div><div class="listItemDetail"><tpl if="listItemDetail != null">{listItemDetail}</tpl></div></div>'
 });


Ext.define('MyApp.store.ListStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.ListData',
    proxy: {
        id: 'ListStore',
        access: 'public'
    }
}
});
```

And in my controller, the store is filled like that,

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore('ListStore');
myStore.setData(jsonData);
myStore.setPageSize(5);
myStore.sync();
```

Paging did not work in this case, anybody has any idea?

Comment: i try to do like this example : [http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/05/sencha-touch-list-load-more.html](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/05/sencha-touch-list-load-more.html)

Comment: The ListPaging plugin will only work with remotely loaded data. Here is example demo http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/touch-build/examples/production/pullrefresh/index.html

Comment: My store is filled with remote data also, login request posted to server and server sends the list data to client. this list data is filled my store. Did I miss something?

Comment: check your current page on remote server and result return?

Comment: There is not store defined in your list's config.

Comment: i add store after i fill it,

var listView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.ListTemplate');
listView.setStore(myStore);

Answer (score 3):

Try this it is similar to what i use & it works for me.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ListTemplate', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
requires: [
    'Ext.plugin.ListPaging'
    ],
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    storeId: 'ListStore',
    plugins: [
        {
            type: 'listpaging',
            autoPaging: true
        }
    ]},
    itemTpl: '<div class="listContainer"><div class="listItemTitle">{listItemTitle}</div><div class="elapsedTime"><tpl if="listItemDate != null">{listItemDate}</tpl></div><div class="listItemDetail"><tpl if="listItemDetail != null">{listItemDetail}</tpl></div></div>'
 });


Ext.define('MyApp.store.ListStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.ListData',
    pageSize: 5,
    storeId: 'ListStore',
    proxy: {
        id: 'ListStore',
        pageParam: 'param' //very important the parameter you use in the server side for pagination
        url: 'somesite.com' //you dont seem to have specified a url
    }
}
});
```